# Is there an equivalent to Python's ImportError in C#

Tags: c#, python

I'm putting together a code base for Unity3d with all sorts of common patterns. It will be imported into a project as source code not a compiled DLL.

Some of the code should only be compiled where a specific dependency (also installed as source code) is present. (In this case, Networking code should only be compiled if Photon is installed in the project).

I could just go through manually delete files that aren't required, however I would prefer some kind of automated way to conditionally compile classes.

If this where Python I could do something like:

```
try:
    import MyLibrary

    class MyClass(self):
        ...

except ImportError:
    # library not imported
```

I know within a class I can use reflection to work out if a class is defined, but is there a way to do this at a higher level, i.e. with something like the pseudocode:

```
#if namespace_defined('ExternalDependency') // <-- how can I do this kind of check?
using ExternalDependency;

public class MyClass { ... } 
#endif
```

Comment: `using` does not reference or include code. `using` makes it easier for the programmer to type type names.

Comment: C# is a `Type Safe` language. Such dynamic dependency resolving can only be done with `reflection` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx)

Comment: I'm aware of the differences between Python's import and C#'s using and type safe vs dynamic languages. I'm more curious whether there is anything the compiler can do to help! Sounds like there might not be.

Comment: The compiler might help, to a degree, if you convert your source files to [T4 templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) where you'd analyze project dependencies before generating the final code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, there's no chance that you could include an `using` clause in a code file as part of a project which doesn't reference the assembly that contains the imported namespace, thus, you won't be able to perform that check.

An `using` of a namespace which can't be located in any of referenced assemblies will produce a compiler error (i.e. *Are you missing a project reference?*).

In other words, C# encourages developers to be sure that all dependencies are available at compile-time.

Actually, if you want to perform different actions in your code depending on some configuration, environment or whatever, it seems like you'll need to stick with [inversion of control design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).